# Issues with Mysql I can't solve

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Issue 1)**

I am wanting to clone a table (both structure and data) to another database on the same server.

I am wondering how I copy this using MySQLi:

```
 CREATE  TABLE  `insurance`.`GD14062013` (  `URN` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `Title` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `FirstName` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `LastName` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `ADD` varchar( 500  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `SUB` varchar( 100  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `STATE` varchar( 100  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `POSTCODE` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `DPID` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `LanLine` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `Mobile` varchar( 30  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `DUP` varchar( 11  )  NOT  NULL ,
 KEY  `LanLine` (  `LanLine` ,  `Mobile`  )  ) ENGINE  = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET  = latin1;

SET SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

INSERT INTO `insurance`.`GD14062013` SELECT * FROM `GDMASTER`.`GD14062013`;
```

**Issue 2)**

I am wanting to drop aka alter columns after I no longer need them. This works:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` ADD  `primary` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL";
$mysqli->query($query); 
$query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` ADD  `alternitive` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

This does not:

```
    $query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` DROP  `primary` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL";
    $mysqli->query($query); 
    $query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` DROP  `alternitive` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL";
    $mysqli->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` DROP  `primary`";
$mysqli->query($query); 
$query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` DROP  `alternitive`";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

There is no need to pass column data type when you are dropping it.

[MySQL ALTER TABLE specyfication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    DROP [COLUMN] col_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't supposed to be

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` DROP COLUMN  `primary`";
$mysqli->query($query); 
$query = "ALTER TABLE  `$table` DROP COLUMN `alternitive`";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Take note of DROP COLUMN. There are other parts of table you can drop in order to alter. Namely `COLUMN`, `INDEX`, `PRIMARY KEY`, and `FOREIGN KEY`.

Refer to the MySQL manual on [altering tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).